# Julia/LLVM Efficient Division of Integer Numbers with Integer Result

Tags: llvm, julia, mathematical-optimization

I ran into a basic type stability issue where dividing two `Integer`s will produce some concrete type of `AbstractFloat`.

```
typeof(60 * 5 / 60)
> Float64
```

Now this is the safe thing to do, but it incurs runtime overhead converting to a float.

What if we know that division will always result in a number with remainder 0, ie. an `Integer`?

We can use either:

```
div(60 * 5 , 60) 
fld(60 * 5 , 60)
```

Which gives us some concrete type of `Integer`, however this approach still has overhead which we can see from the LLVM IR:

```
@code_llvm  div(60 * 5 , 60)
```

**So is there any magic we can do to remove the runtime overhead when we know that the result will not have a remainder?**

Possible Solution Paths:

I would prefer this be solved using a Julia construct, even if we need to create it, rather than injecting LLVM IR... But then again, we could just wrap that injection into a Julia function...

Or maybe we need a macro like `@inbounds` for safe integer division resulting in an integer.

Or maybe there is some purely mathematical way to perform this that applies to any language?

Comment: note: reducing visual overhead is possible with `\div<tab>` which produces `÷`. `a÷b` is equivalent to `div(a,b)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Integer division is one of the slowest cache-independent operations on a CPU; indeed, floating-point division is faster on most CPUs (test it yourself and see). If you know what you'll be dividing by in advance (and want to divide by it many times), it can be worth precomputing factors that allow you to replace integer-division with multiplication/shift/add. There are many sites that describe this basic idea, [here's one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdev/archive/2005/12/12/502980.aspx).

For an implementation in julia, see
https://gist.github.com/simonster/a3b691e71cc2b3826e39

Comment: Update: Julia now has non-exported `SignedMultiplicativeInverse` and `UnsignedMultiplicativeInverse` types that allow you to use this trick without having to write the code yourself.

Answer (score 11):

You're right — there is a little bit of overhead in the `div` function, but it's not because there may be a remainder.  It's because `div(typemin(Int),-1)` is an error, as is `div(x, 0)`.  So the overhead you're seeing in `@code_llvm` is just the checks for those cases.  The LLVM instruction that you want is just [`sdiv i64 %0, %1`](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#sdiv-instruction)… and the processor will even throw a [SIGFPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGFPE) in those error conditions.  We can use `llvmcall` to create our own "overhead-free" version:

```
julia> unsafe_div(x::Int64,y::Int64) = Base.llvmcall("""
           %3 = sdiv i64 %0, %1
           ret i64 %3""", Int64, Tuple{Int64, Int64}, x, y)
unsafe_div (generic function with 1 method)

julia> unsafe_div(8,3)
2

julia> @code_llvm unsafe_div(8,3)

define i64 @julia_unsafe_div_21585(i64, i64) {
top:
  %2 = sdiv i64 %0, %1
  ret i64 %2
}

julia> unsafe_div(8,0)
ERROR: DivideError: integer division error
 in unsafe_div at none:1
```

So if that works, why does Julia insist on inserting those checks into the LLVM IR itself?  It's because LLVM considers those error cases to be undefined behavior within its optimization passes.  So if LLVM can ever prove that it would error through static analysis, it *changes its output* to skip the division (and subsequent exception) entirely!  This custom div function is indeed unsafe:

```
julia> f() = unsafe_div(8,0)
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> f()
13315560704

julia> @code_llvm f()

define i64 @julia_f_21626() {
top:
  ret i64 undef
}
```

On my machine (an old Nehalem i5), this unsafe version can speed `div` up by about 5-10%, so the overhead here isn't really all that terrible relative to the inherent cost of integer division.  As [@tholy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1939814/tholy) notes, it's still really slow compared to almost all other CPU operations, so if you're frequently dividing by the same number, you may want to investigate the alternatives in his answer.

Comment: For more details on plans to eliminate this overhead, see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8188.

Comment: Insightful, thanks.  I am going to compare both approaches with the addition of floating point only, and see what is fastest.  This is for a low latency path, otherwise I would be using safe ops.

Comment: An even less safe option would be floating point operations: `fdiv(x,y) = Base.unsafe_trunc(Int, x/y)`.  Only works for integers up to `maxintfloat(Float64)`, but is ~25% faster on my machine (YMMV depending on architecture).